# How to set orientation and copies dynamically with pageDialog?

Tags: java, printing

When I call my `pageDialog` with `printerJob.pageDialog(pageFormat)`, the dialog box pops up as it should prompting the user to modify the page format of the print job.

Some settings work however some do not such as the orientation radio buttons.

I know I need to use the `setOrientation` method however, how can I retrieve information from the dialog box such as which radio button did the user click on for portrait or landscape?

Same goes for retrieving the information for how many copies did the user request from the `printerJob.printDialog` method?

Thank you